# Xcode не видит заголовочного файла

Tags: c++, xcode

[image]

Вчера обновила macbook до Catalina, а также Xcode до последней доступной версии. Теперь компилятор сообщает, что не видит стандартных библиотек C++. Но все компилируется как и раньше. В чем может быть проблема? Спасибо

Comment: Вы не видите противоречия в "компилятор сообщает, что не видит стандартных библиотек C++" и " Но все компилируется как и раньше"? Об ошибке вам сообщает скорее всего не компилятор, а статический анализатор, clang наверное.